# Filter entries with a script condition

Tags: elasticsearch

Using ElasticSearch 7.16.3, I want to define a filter to return all my products where `value` is superior to `minimum` + 30%

I have this query for now:

```
GET product_price/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": """
            return doc['value'].value >= (doc['minimum'].value + (doc['minimum'].value * 30 / 100));
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I get this error:

> "reason" : "A document doesn't have a value for a field! Use
> doc[].size()==0 to check if a document is missing a field!"

My `minimum` field can be null, so of course I don't want to apply filter on this. I tried to test the field, but since it's a `double`, I can't check if it's null or not.

Is there a good way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to apply the formula only if both fields exist, like this:

```
GET product_price/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "minimum"
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": """
                return doc['value'].value >= (doc['minimum'].value + (doc['minimum'].value * 30 / 100));
            """
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Clean, I was lost trying to use bool & must to group my filters, didn't know we could just have an array of filters. Very clean, thanks !

Comment: Just, I know exists is the good way, but hope next versions will use a better way to test if null or not, exists is for me different of null. isset function would be more logicial imo.